# sql date conversion doesn't work with wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm using the following code during a ajax call on wordpress :

```
$quote_infos = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT quantity, price, post_title AS name, validated, user_login
FROM {$quotes_details_table} 
INNER JOIN {$posts_table} ON {$quotes_details_table}.product_id = {$posts_table}.ID
INNER JOIN {$quotes_table} ON {$quotes_details_table}.quote_id = {$quotes_table}.id
INNER JOIN {$users_table} ON {$quotes_table}.id_client = {$users_table}.ID
WHERE {$quotes_details_table}.quote_id = %s", $quote_id
));
$quote_infos = json_encode($quote_infos);
echo $quote_infos;
wp_die();
```

This code works fine.

But when i try to convert my validated field (which is in DATETIME FORMAT) this way :

```
"SELECT quantity, price, post_title AS name, DATE_FORMAT(validated, '%d/%m/%Y'), user_login...
```

My code doesn't work anymore and return null.

Do you have any idea of the origin of my problem?

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Because its not obvious why this specific change (if thats really all you changed) would cause a problem

Comment: Do you mean it returns NULL for the formatted date? Or Null for the whole query result??

Comment: When i display my parsed ajax response this way :
quote_details = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(quote_details);
My console answer null to my console.log.

Comment: So did you look at the network tab in the debugger to see what was actually being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the origin of my problem :

I am using $wpdb-prepare in my request. And i just saw in the documentation (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) that i need to add add a "%" in my format, like this :

DATE_FORMAT(validated, '**%**%d/**%**%m/**%**%Y') instead of DATE_FORMAT(validated, '%d/%m/%Y').

Thank you very much @RiggsFolly for trying to help me.